# Performances considerations when using referenced assemblies compiled with an older .NET release

Tags: .net, performance, .net-assembly

Despite of being old, [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) is mature, stable and fulfill very well its job in server production code.

However, I noticed that the AForge that comes with NuGet is compiled with NET 2.0. I am using .NET 4.5.2.

Because I need AForge for a client application that will process Video streams, I wonder if there any performance penalty in general when I use referenced assemblies that are compiled with older .NET releases.

Comment: No.  The MSIL in .NET 4.x assembly is not different from the MSIL in .NET 2.0.  Produced by the C# compiler, it does not optimize code.  The programmer does it first, the jitter finishes the job.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanations. I feel reassured. If I dare to ask, is there any reason you answered in a comment ?